# Best way to divide floats

Tags: javascript, node.js, math

I'm working on a REST API that syncs client with the server's time to keep the client in sync and avoid any connection issues. I encountered this issue while dividing floats (I was doing server time (epoch) calculations):

`1672866847.265 + (208420 / 1000)` results in `1672867055.6850002` (which I know is IEEE 754)

mean while according to Google's calculator, it should be `1672867055.69`

Is there a way to solve this issue?

Comment: Does this `1672867055.69` what you are trying to get?

Comment: Yes, according to any calculator out there, that's what the result should be.

Comment: Maybe I did something wrong, but how `0.265 + 0.42` can sum up to `0.69`?

Comment: You can paste that calculation in my question to Google and get the 2nd result I also posted

Comment: I wouldn't rely on google https://www.cymath.com/answer?q=1672866847.265%20%2B%20(208420%20%2F%201000) Google just rounded things up

Comment: Both values are correct; google has rounded the second decimal point. Use `.toFixed(2)`, and you'll get the exact same behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `toFixed(2)` to get 2 decimal points:

`console.log((1672866847.265 + 208420 / 1000).toFixed(2));`

Answer (score 1):

If you want your result to be more reliable try first multiplying

```js
console.log(1672866847.265 + (208420 / 1000))
console.log((1672866847.265 * 1000 + 208420) / 1000)
```

You can also use a library

```js
console.log(new Big(1672866847.265).plus(new Big(208420).div(1000)).toNumber())
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/big.js@6.2.1/big.min.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `round` to avoid decimal values -

```
Math.round(1672867055.6850002);  // ans will be: 1672867056
```

To get value with two decimal point, you can mupltiply it by 100 and then divid it by 100

```
Math.round(1672867055.6850002 * 100)/100;   // ans will be: 1672867055.69
```